# Не работает useSelector, когда dispatch в useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hook, useeffect, redux-toolkit

Пытаюсь сохранить координаты в store, при отрисовке компонента с помощью кода:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
        const top = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        dispatch(setCoordinate([{ top: top - 30, left: ref.current.offsetWidth - 50 - 64 }]))
    }

})
```

Почему-то переменная coordinate при этом не обновляется

```
function Client(props: IClient) {

    const coordinate = useAppSelector((state) => state.areaCoordinateReducer);
    const startTouch = () => {
        console.log(coordinate);
    }
return (<> <div className="client" onTouchStart={startTouch}></div> </>)
```

В чем может быть проблема? Или может есть идеи как можно по-другому сохранить координаты не связанного компонента?

Код reducer:

```
export const coordinateSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'areaCoordinate',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setCoordinate(state, action: PayloadAction<IAreaCoordinate[]>) {
            console.log(state);

            state = [...action.payload];
            console.log(state);


        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в reducer
Неправильно записывала новое значение в state

```
export const coordinateSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'areaCoordinate',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setCoordinate(state, action: PayloadAction<IAreaCoordinate[]>) {
            state.arr = [...action.payload];
        },
    },
});
```